# Angular4 - confusion about NgModel and ngModel,

Tags: angular

I am going thought tutorial that explains that **FormsModule** gives us a template driven directives such as **ngModel**.

But I can see in my app.module.ts -
`import {NgModel} from '@angular/core'`

So **NgModel** does not provide **ngModel** directive...?

Comment: `ngModel` is just selector of `NgModel` directive

Comment: You should import FormsModule to access to NgModel directive otherwise it won't work properly in some cases

Comment: @yurzui - Oh, I am sorry, just now I rechecked my files and actually I was talking about `NgModule`, but now as I see it lexically very different from `NgModel`, my confusion went away.  Thanks for info anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NgModel` is an export from the framework, while `ngModel` is a tag attribute used to bind a value to an HTML element.

Both cases follow syntax rules : `NgModel` is in pascal case, and `ngModel` is in camel case. [More information here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx)